# Pythonで "ValueError: not enough values to unpack" エラーが発生する

Tags: python, python3

アーチェリー用のプレイヤーの名前とIDを入力した後、当たった場所を入力させて得点を計算し、
得点の多い順に並べるプログラムを制作しているのですが、いざ動かそうとしたら

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 13, got 12)
```

という見慣れないエラーが出てしまいました。

調べるとどうやら「変数の数と要素の数が一致していない」とこのエラーが出ると書いてありましたが、関数 `set_values` の戻り値を

```
return Memberlist,MemberID,Playerlist,PlayerID,NoofPlayer,maxshoot,Nooftargets,NoofPG,Round,Noofarrows,NoofLays,Podium
```

から

```
return Memberlist,MemberID,Playerlist,PlayerID,NoofPlayer,maxshoot,Nooftargets,NoofPG,Round,score,Noofarrows,NoofLays,Podium
```

にするとそもそも動かなくなってしまいます。
このエラーに関する解決策や改善点を教えてくれると幸いです。

```py
import datetime

def set_up_players() :
    Assignment = True
    Memberlist = [] # Local  list
    MemberID = []   # Local  list
    while Assignment == True :
        print("")
        membership = str(input("Are you assigned already? Answer Y for 'Yes' N for 'No' :"))
        if membership == "Y" :
            y1 = int(input("Enter your year to assign your membership. :"))
            m1 = int(input("Enter your month to assign your membership. :"))
            d1 = int(input("Enter your day to assign your membership. :"))
            dt1 = datetime.datetime(year=y1, month=m1, day=d1)
            time = datetime.datetime.now() - dt1
            daytime = int((time.days))
            print(daytime)
            if daytime > 1096 :
                print("You need to renew your membership.")
                print("Go to office to renew you membership card.")
            else :
                print("Welcom back to our Archely club")
        elif membership == "N" :
            check = False
            print("You need to make your membership")
            name = str(input("Enter your name. :"))
            while check == False :
                id = str(input("Enter any 5 digit number :"))
                if (id in MemberID) == True:
                    print ("Sorry it's already in list, Try again.")
                else :
                    check = True
            Memberlist.append(name)
            MenberID.append(id)
        else :
            print("Answer in Y or N.")
        print("")
        Assign = str(input("Finish assignment?? Answer Y for 'Yes' N for 'No' : "))
        if Assign == "N" :
            Assignment = True
        elif Assign == "Y" :
            Assignment = False
        else :
            print("Answer in Y or N.")


    return Memberlist,MemberID # 多分問題ナシ

def sign_up_players(MemberID) :
    Playerlist = []
    PlayerID = []
    player_count = 0
    while player_count == 5:
        id = str(input("Enter your  5 digit ID. :"))
        if (id in MemberID) == True:
            name = str(input("Enter your name. :"))
            Playerlist.append(name)
            PlayerID.append(id)
            player_count = player_count + 1
            print(player_count)
        else :
            print("Sorry but Register first.")


    return MemberID,Playerlist,PlayerID

def set_score(NoofPlayer) :
    score = []
    counter = NoofPlayer 
    for i in range (counter) :
        score.append(0)
    return NoofPlayer, score

def set_values () :
    Memberlist,MemberID = set_up_players()
    MemberID,Playerlist,PlayerID = sign_up_players(MenberID)
    NoofPlayer = int(len(Playerlist))
    maxshoot = 5
    set_score(NoofPlayer)
    Nooftargets = NoofPlayer
    NoofPG = NoofPlayer
    Round = 5
    Noofarrows = 1*Round*NoofPlayer
    NoofLays = NoofPlayer
    Podium = NoofPlayer
    return Memberlist,MemberID,Playerlist,PlayerID,NoofPlayer,maxshoot,Nooftargets,NoofPG,Round,Noofarrows,NoofLays,Podium　#戻り値をいじくったのはこの関数です

def Allocate_Equipment(NoofPlayer) :
    ownarrows = []
    ownbows = []
    ownPG = []
    co = NoofPlayer
    while co > 0 :
        arrows = str(input("Do you have your own arrows? Answer Y for 'Yes' N for 'No' :'"))
        if arrows == "Y" :
            ownarrows.append(yes)
        else :
            ownarrows.append(no)
        PG = str(input("Do you have your own PG? Answer Y for 'Yes' N for 'No' :'"))
        if PG == "Y" :
            ownPG.append(yes)
        else :
            ownPG.append(no)
        bows = str(input("Do you have your own bow? Answer Y for 'Yes' N for 'No' :'"))
        if bows == "Y" :
            ownbows.append(yes)
        else :
            ownbows.append(no)
        co = co - 1
    print(ownarrows,ownPG,ownbows)

    return NoofPlayer, ownarrows, ownbows, ownPG

def shooting_arrows (Playerlist,NoofPlayer,Round,score) :
    RoundTime = 0
    while Round > RoundTime :
        PlayerShoot = 0
        while PlayerShoot < Round :
            CurrentPlayer = 1
            while NoofPlayer > CurrentPlayer :
                Player_shoot_arrow(Playerlist,CurrentPlayer)
                Updata_score(score,CurrentPlayer,hitplace)
                Displayscore(Playerlist,NoofPlayer,score)
                CurrentPlayer = CurrentPlayer + 1
            PlayerShoot = PlayerShoot + 1
        RoundTime = RoundTime + 1


    return Playerlist,NoofPlayer,Round,score,RoundTime,PlayerShoot,CurrentPlayer

def Player_shoot_arrow(Playerlist,CurrentPlayer) :
    print("It's "  , Playerlist[CurrentPlayer],  "'s turn.")
    hitplace = str(input("Where did you get? :"))
    return Playerlist,CurrentPlayer,hitplace

def Updata_score(score,CurrentPlayer,hitplace) :
    if hitplace == "A":
        score[CurrentPlayer] = score[CurrentPlayer] + 100
    elif hitplace == "B":
        score[CurrentPlayer] = score[CurrentPlayer] + 50
    elif hitplace == "C":
        score[CurrentPlayer] = score[CurrentPlayer] + 10


    return score,CurrentPlayer,hitplace

def Displayscore(Playerlist,NoofPlayer,score) :
    for i in range (NoofPlayer):
        print(Playerlist[NoofPlayer], + "'s score is " , + score[NoofPlayer])

    return Playerlist,NoofPlayer,score

def score_board(Playerlist,NoofPlayer,Podium,score) :
    Displayscore(Playerlist,NoofPlayer,score)
    scorelist = []
    scorelist = score
    score.sort(reverse=True)
    Podium = len(score)
    third = score[2]
    second = score[1]
    first = score[0]
    print("Third Player is "  , Playerlist[scorelist.index(third)] ,  "who get " , scorelist[2])
    print("Third Player is "  , Playerlist[scorelist.index(second)] ,  "who get " , scorelist[1])
    print("Third Player is "  , Playerlist[scorelist.index(first)] ,  "who get " , scorelist[0])
    return Playerlist,NoofPlayer,Podium,score,scorelist


Memberlist,MemberID,Playerlist,PlayerID,NoofPlayer,maxshoot,Nooftargets,NoofPG,Round,score,Noofarrows,NoofLays,Podium = set_values ()# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 13, got 12) 
Allocate_Equipment(NoofPlayer)
Playerlist,NoofPlayer,Round,score = shooting_arrows (Playerlist,NoofPlayer,Round,score)
score_board(Playerlist,NoofPlayer,Podium,score)
```

Answer (score 1):

エラーの意味は、set_values関数の戻り値は12個だが、13個あるかのように書いているため変数格納できないという意味です。

```py
Memberlist,MemberID,Playerlist,PlayerID,NoofPlayer,maxshoot,Nooftargets,NoofPG,Round,score,Noofarrows,NoofLays,Podium = set_values ()
```

ここで13個戻り値を期待しているのに、そもそも関数は

```py
def set_values () :
    Memberlist,MemberID = set_up_players()
    MemberID,Playerlist,PlayerID = sign_up_players(MenberID)
    NoofPlayer = int(len(Playerlist))
    maxshoot = 5
    set_score(NoofPlayer)
    Nooftargets = NoofPlayer
    NoofPG = NoofPlayer
    Round = 5
    Noofarrows = 1*Round*NoofPlayer
    NoofLays = NoofPlayer
    Podium = NoofPlayer
    return Memberlist,MemberID,Playerlist,PlayerID,NoofPlayer,maxshoot,Nooftargets,NoofPG,Round,Noofarrows,NoofLays,Podium　#戻り値をいじくったのはこの関数です
```

12個しか戻り値を返していないため不整合が起きています

どう直すかですが、set_scoreの戻り値を関数内で受け取って返せば良いと思います。

```py
def set_values () :
    Memberlist,MemberID = set_up_players()
    MemberID,Playerlist,PlayerID = sign_up_players(MenberID)
    NoofPlayer = int(len(Playerlist))
    maxshoot = 5
    _, score = set_score(NoofPlayer) # ココ
    Nooftargets = NoofPlayer
    NoofPG = NoofPlayer
    Round = 5
    Noofarrows = 1*Round*NoofPlayer
    NoofLays = NoofPlayer
    Podium = NoofPlayer
    return Memberlist,MemberID,Playerlist,PlayerID,NoofPlayer,maxshoot,Nooftargets,NoofPG,Round,score,Noofarrows,NoofLays,Podium # 返り値も直す
```